# Java 8 - What is the real time usecase for return method from another method?

Tags: java, oop, java-8, callback, functional-programming

As we know , Java 8 supports functional programming.

We can pass method as a parameter and return a method from another method.

I know , call back is one of the real time usecase for passing method as parameter . But I couldn't find any real usecase for returning method from another method . Please give me some real time example for this.

Comment: return a method from another method? what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: that question is not about Java. can you show a basic example of what you mean in Java?

Comment: @Stultuske the question is about Java 8 which supports functional programming. I believe OP is referring to High Order functions (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/index.html#higher-order-functions)

Comment: @CharalamposAnargyrou it's about Java8, that I get, it's the "returning method from another method" part I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples of taking/returning functional interfaces in the JDK itself.

Here are some use cases that are obvious:

*"Standard" logic*:

```
Function.identity() //standard implementation for obj -> obj
```

*Logic chaining* (function composition):

```
Function<String, String> upperCase = String::toUpperCase;
Function<String, String> upperCaseAndTrim = upperCase.andThen(String::trim);
```

`andThen` is a composition of functions, and it's only logical to return a functional interface.

And a related use case:

```
ToIntFunction<String> intExtractor = String::length;
Comparator<String> stringLengthComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(intExtractor);
```

Here, a standard `int` comparator is created by `Comparator`, taking a function that knows how to produce an `int` from the collection element type.

*This is probably another case of composed functions*:

```
Predicate<String> isValid = s -> s.length() <= 10;
Predicate<String> isInvalid = isValid.negate();
```

`negate()` reverses the logic implemented by the original method.

Comment: Your answer is way better than my answer :(

Answer (score 1):

The 'methods' you talk about are called lambdas and they are a powerful tool, because they are more than they initially seem. On the first look a lambda is nothing but behavior wrapped in slim syntax. But actually a lambda can do much more.

For example, lambdas 'capture' values they use from their respective scope at creation time:

```
...
final MyType t = someObject;
Runnable runner = () -> t.someMethod();
return runner;
...

...
runner.run();
```

This is actually a call to the `someMethod` of the object `someObject`. This means, that a lambda actually has a context at the position it is created, as opposed to where it is called.

But there is more: You can actually pass just a method (as you describe), if the method fits the specific signature of the expected interface:

```
List<String> myStrings = ...;
myStrings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

As you can see, you can actually link object-specific methods, not just static ones. Once again, you have passed context.

Now to the specific question: Why return a method-lambda from a method call?

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> handlers = new HashMap<>();
...

public Consumer<String> getHandler(String key) {
    Consumer<String> h = handlers.get(key);
    if (h == null) {
        return System.out::println;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Now you can link the handler you store somewhere central to another object, for which you define a behavior.